# Is it possible to set Google Docs as the default text editor on Windows?

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way to set Google Docs as the default text editor on Windows 7, so that any local text files that are opened will be opened in Google Docs? In order for this to be possible, it would need to be available as a feature of Google Drive (or a similar application), but I'm not sure if such a feature has been implemented yet.

Comment: It looks like it might be possible to [open local documents using Google Docs](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/how-do-i-get-local-documents-to-directly-open-in-google-docs). Actually, there's a program called GDocsOpen that does exactly that. :)